# tablesorter jquery plugin and responsive webdesign

Tags: jquery, html, css, responsive-design, tablesorter

I have experience with the `tablesorter` jQuery plugin on desktop. But is the `tablesorter` jQuery plugin suitable for websites where responsive webdesign is needed? Do you have some experience with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My [fork of tablesorter](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/) includes a [reflow widget](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-widget-reflow.html) which will restructure the data and keep everything sortable for smaller screens. There are two different "flavors" of the widget, one for single row headers and the other for multirow headers, try out the demo.

Comment: Thank you very much Rob!

Answer (score 1):

Get the latest version of table sorter from here:
https://www.versioneye.com/javascript/mottie:jquery.tablesorter/2.28.5
Extract the files some where on your computer. I have extracted mine on my wamp directory.
Then follow this demo:
file:///C:/wamp64/www/monarch/Mottie-tablesorter-aa0266c/docs/index.html#Demo

...Works great.!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I have used this. Tablesorter is a manageable jQuery plugin that offers dynamic row sorting based on the values of one or more given column. And also provides the possibility to paginate tables created using the HTML table element.